# How to measure Migration time and Down time

Tags: migration, virtual-machine, kvm

[1]I am using KVM with virt-manager to migrate the virtual machines from one system to another.

To calculate migration time I run the following command at host machine terminal:

```
time virsh migrate --live UBVM1 qemu+ssh://server1.example.com
```

And it is showing following output

```
real    0m15.430s
user    0m0.031s
sys 0m0.015s
```

Now, I am slight bit confused that which above value is migration time

Answer (score 0):

The number you're interested in is the `real` value, which is the amount of actual ("wall-clock") time which elapsed between the beginning of the `time`d command and its completion.

As for the other numbers, `user` is the amount of time that the CPU spent running user-mode code and `sys` is the amount of time it spend on kernel-mode (`sys`tem) code.  In this case, those numbers are much smaller than the `real` time because VM migration is primarily an I/O task (sending data across the network) and doesn't require the CPU do to much other than wait for the network to finish moving the data.

---

Addition to answer OP's followup question in comments about how to determine downtime during migration:

In principle, there is no downtime whatsoever when doing a live migration.  The way the live migration process works is that it starts the VM on the destination node in a 'paused' state, sends the contents of the VM's RAM over the network while the VM remains active on the origin node, then continues sending updates of changed RAM content until both versions of the VM have identical memory contents.  Once they're identical, the VM on the destination node goes live and the VM on the origin node is simultaneously shut down.  Of course, the synchronization can never be absolutely perfect, but the gap during which neither instance is running should be on the order of a few milliseconds, if not less.

However, in practice, it takes a somewhat longer time for your nodes' virtual bridges and the physical network infrastructure to recognize that traffic to the VM's IP address needs to be rerouted to a different physical interface (i.e., packets need to stop going to the origin node and go to the destination node instead).  In the few tests I've done in my environment, the VM is generally inaccessible for 30 seconds after doing a live migration.  To test this in your environment, start up a continuous `ping` to the migrating VM's IP address before moving it, then look at the ping output after the migration is complete to see how long the VM stopped responding for.

Comment: Thanks Sir, also please tell me how to measure downtime. I tried every possible solution but not getting the same.

Comment: @aditya - I've edited my answer to cover your question about downtime, since it's a bit to long for a comment.